# Websocket redirect using FastAPI

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

#### Websocket Redirect

I have two services, one have a websocket server on it for live transcription , but the client can only connect with the first one. What I want to do is in the following image :
[image: ws_redirect]

I checked the documentation, and the closest I can get is from the [RedirectResponse section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=redirect#redirectresponse)  :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/typer")
### Websocket Redirect
I have two services, one have a websocket server on it for live transcription , but the client can only connect with the first
async def read_typer():
    return RedirectResponse("https://typer.tiangolo.com")
```

I would apperciate any help.
Thank you !

Comment: Perhaps it will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361686/websockets-stream-audio-in-json-out-w-fastapi-and-two-websockets/65395702

Comment: Thx @alex_noname, but this is the solution I want to avoid. I don't want the gateway to intercept the data. Just redirect the URL to another one.

Comment: You cannot really do it without some form of intercepting. HTTP redirects won't allow you to pass the data from resource directly inaccessible for user, as they are browser based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Websockets bridge for audio stream in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361686/websockets-bridge-for-audio-stream-in-fastapi)

Comment: I want to leave bridge as a last resort. I will try using a proxy server atm, maybe it will do.